# Convert static to dynamic import in Typescript

Tags: typescript, express, typescript2.0, express-session

I have an Express.js application written in TypeScript (2.7.1) and I'm trying to dynamically import `express-session` module. In my understanding `import session from 'express-session'` should be equivalent to `let session = await import('express-session')` however the static import work just fine (if `express-session` is installed) while the dynamic version complains:

```
error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. 
Type '{ default: typeof session; Store: typeof Store; MemoryStore: typeof MemoryStore; }' 
has no compatible call signatures
```

Here is what my file looks like after removing the static import and surrounding the import with `try-catch`:

```js
import express from 'express'

export class MyServer {
  public app: express.Application

  constructor() {
    this.app = express()
    this.init()
  }

  async init() {
    try {

      const session = await import('express-session')

      this.app.use(session({secret: 'my_secure_secret'}))
      this.app.set('hasSession', true)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Failed to load session, continue without it')
      this.app.set('hasSession', false)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `import()` function does actually import the whole *CommonJS*  `exports` object. Checking the types from `@types/express-session` we have:

```js
[...]
declare function session(options?: session.SessionOptions): express.RequestHandler;

declare namespace session {
  interface SessionOptions {
    secret: string | string[];
    name?: string;
    store?: Store | MemoryStore;
    cookie?: express.CookieOptions;
    genid?(req: express.Request): string;
    rolling?: boolean;
    resave?: boolean;
    proxy?: boolean;
    saveUninitialized?: boolean;
    unset?: string;
  }
[...]
export = session;
```

At this point `export = session` actually is equivalent to `exports.default = session` (still a bit confusing that compiler understands `session` as reference of the *function* and not as *namespace*)  and this leads to the solution:

```js
  async init() {
    try {

      const session = (await import('express-session')).default

      this.app.use(session({secret: 'my_secure_secret'}))
      this.app.set('hasSession', true)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Failed to load session, continue without it')
      this.app.set('hasSession', false)
    }
```